# Dell switch Remote Log output structure

Tags: switch, syslog

I am looking for information on what each part of a remote log(syslog) entry is from a Dell PowerConnect or Dell N series switch.

I have the following log entry of:

```
<190> May 15 11:06:19 10.10.9.1-1 CLI_WEB[89546900]: cmd_logger_api.c(260) 8930 %% [WEB:admin:10.11.11.127] User has succesfully logged in
```

I see it goes:

- PRI
- Month
- Day
- Time
- **(Outgoing host IP or lowest IP on switch) ?**
- Component
- PID
- Executable
- **(Unknown number after executable) ?**
- **(Unknown number) ?**
- Message

Anyone be able to shed a little better light on this?

Here are a few more entries from some other switches:

```
<190> May 15 11:36:12 10.11.9.1-1 UNITMGR[842641108]: unitmgr.c(6794) 7803 %% Copy of running configuration to backup unit complete
<190> May 15 11:43:34 10.10.9.1-1 CLI_WEB[89546900]: cmd_logger_api.c(260) 8937 %% [WEB:admin:10.10.10.12] Disconnected due to Idle Timeout
<189> MAY 15 08:08:49 10.10.50.30-1 TRAPMGR[152633056]: traputil.c(611) 8151 %% 1/0/42 is transitioned from the Learning state to the Forwarding state in instance 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the manual that shows the format. The format is as follows:

PRI Timestamp HostIP Address StackID Component Name Thread ID File name line number sequence number message